# play Audio tag onload in a specific time(ogg/mp3) using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Load Audio tag in a specific time(mp3) using javascript.
Current code bellow, complety ignores currentTime.
My objective is to autoplay a mp3 file based on time(seconds) of the computer hardware clock.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<button onclick="setCurTime()" type="button">Set time position to 5 seconds</button>
<br> 


<audio id="audio1"  controls="controls">
  <source src="http://attackbeat.com/audio/Masayume%20Chasing.mp3" type="audio/mp3">

  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</audio>

<script>
   var time = new Date();
 var timex = time.getSeconds();
myAudio=document.getElementById("audio1");

window.onload = function () {

myAudio.play();
myAudio.currentTime=10;
}
function setCurTime()
  { 

  myAudio.currentTime=timex;
myAudio.play();
  } 
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can seek to the given time only once the [meta data](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#dom-media-have_metadata) is available:

```
var audio = document.getElementById('audio1');

audio.onloadedmetadata = function() {
  audio.currentTime = new Date().getSeconds(); // autoplay based on current time (seconds)
  audio.play();
};
```